# javascript timing events... what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

im trying to run an ajax request to determine if a blob has been uploaded to cloud. 
it needs to try for about 10 seconds before exiting gracefully. I have it wired to another function

```
 function rotatePhotographImage(rotation, photoId) {
    $("#ImagePhoto").attr('src', './Images/Loading/loading.gif');

$.getJSON('/api/blob/RotateBlobImage',
    {
        fileid: photoId,
        rotation: rotation,
    })
    .done(function (data) {

       alert("The rotation request was successful, however this does take a few moments to upload to the cloud.");
        assertBlobExists(data);
    });
}
```

its hitting my assertBlobExists function but when in there.. it just starts hitting my api as fast as it can.. it seem to completely ignore the setTimeout function. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
function assertBlobExists(blobfilename) {

$.get('/api/blob/ValidateBlobExists',
    { id: blobfilename })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    if (data === true) {
        $("#ImagePhoto").attr('src',  blobfilename);
        return;
    }
});

setTimeout(assertBlobExists(blobfilename), 3000);

}
```

It just freezes out my page and I end up having to process thousands of threads.

Comment: Put ur api call inside setTimeout callback

Comment: `setTimeout(assertBlobExists(blobfilename), 3000);` isnt actually waiting, it's being called right away - you want `setTimeout(function() { assertBlobExists(blobfilename) }, 3000);`

Comment: You have poor _separation of concerns_.   Your code would benefit from separating out the AJAX code from the DOM manipulation code.

Comment: Thanks tymeJV I'll give that a shot. I hoped it was something obvious.